# Symfony 2 How to check the cookie is set

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

```
namespace AppBundle\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


class lastChangeTimeHelper
{
protected $em;
protected $user;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, SecurityContext $securityContext)
{
    $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function lastChangeTime()
{
    $user = $this->user;
    $em = $this->em;

    $response = new Response();

    if (null == $response->headers->getCookies())
    {
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lastChangeTime', time(), time() + (3600 * 48)));
    }

    $currentCookieValue = $response->headers->getCookies()['0']->getValue();
    $currentTime = time();
    $maxTime = 60;

    if ($currentTime-$currentCookieValue < $maxTime)
    {
        $currentCookieValue = $currentTime;
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lastChangeTime', $currentCookieValue, time() + (3600 * 48)));
    } else {
        $user->setTime(time());
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
}
```

I have no idea how to properly check the cookie called **lastChangeTime** is set. I would create one if it is not. **$currentCookieValue** and **$currentTime** always have same value. It seems like my script create a new cookie everytime i'm trying to call function **lastChangeTimeHelper::lastChangeTime()**.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `request` to get the cookie?
Try: `$request->cookies->get('lastChangeTime');` ?

Comment: It could work, the code above is a service. How to get access to Request data?

Comment: `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; $request = Request::createFromGlobals();` ?

Comment: Which line is it in your code?

Comment: `$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        if (null == $request->cookies->get('lastChangeTime'));
        {
            $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lastChangeTime', time(), time() + (3600 * 48)));
        }` now it works, but i still have problem, $currentCookieValue and $currentTime have same value, but they shouldn't

Comment: Take a look at the code I've added below. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 2):

Use `request` to get current cookies, you can use the `has()` action to check if it exists and later use the `get()` action to get its value. See the following code:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$cookies = $request->cookies;

if (!$cookies->has('lastChangeTime'))
{
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lastChangeTime', time(), time() + (3600 * 48)));
}
else
{
    $currentCookieValue = $cookies->get('lastChangeTime');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $cookies = $request->cookies;

    if (!$cookies->has('lastChangeTime')) {
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lastChangeTime', time(), time() + (3600 * 48)));
    } else {
        $currentCookieValue = $cookies->get('lastChangeTime');
    }

    if ($currentTime-$currentCookieValue < $maxTime)
```

Variable `$currentCookieValue` in `if ($currentTime-$currentCookieValue < $maxTime)` is not defined. When I `var_dump($cookies)` it returns me a

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#400 (1) { ["parameters":protected]=> array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "vq0mf8ll7hmq1fae6kqjtfg185" } }
```

but as you can see there is not `lastChangeTime` cookie.

Comment: You shouldn't add your code as an answer, rather as an update to your question. If you write `var_dump($cookies->get('lastChangeTime'));`. What's the output?

Comment: and `var_dump($cookies->has('lastChangeTime'));`?

Comment: so even if i created new cookie and then `var_dump($cookies->has('lastChangeTime'))` it returned false